# Why can't I retrieve an optional argument for method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this simple method:

```
 def has_kontakt?(*depa)
   return JSON.parse(self.kontakte).include?(*depa.to_s)
 end
```

You can see I defined `depa` as an optional argument.
Somehow the argument cannot be retrived using `include?(*depa.to_s)`.

Previously I had:

```
 def has_kontakt?(depa)
   return JSON.parse(self.kontakte).include?(depa.to_s)
 end
```

And all worked well. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `*depa` is not an optional argument. It's splatted argument. There's difference.

Comment: Can you please write me a answer, how i define a optional argument? Thanks

Comment: Now I can read the post properly and understood... :)

Comment: `depa.to_s` isn't probably what you want with `*depa`. Converting an array (`*depa`) to a string will really reduce the likelihood that `include?` will find a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an asterisk before an argument does not mark it as optional. Instead, it allows you to pass any number of arguments which are then passed to the method as an array:

```
def method(*args)
  puts args.inspect
end

method :foo
# => [:foo]

method foo, :bar, :baz
# => [:foo, :bar, :baz]
```

Because of that, `*depa.to_s` isn't really useful. I guess, you either want to actually define an optional argument by adding a default value like this:

```
def has_kontakt?(depa="")
   return JSON.parse(self.kontakte).include?(depa.to_s)
end
```

or you want to properly handle the array (depending on what you actually want to achieve)

```
def has_kontakt?(*depa)
   # return true if all depa values are contained in self.kontakte (assuming it's an array)
   return (depa & JSON.parse(self.kontakte)) == depa
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way that you define optional arguments. The * is a splat operator (http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). You want an optional argument, which would look more like this:

```
def has_kontakt?(depa=nil)
  if depa.nil?
    # no argument was passed in
  else
    # depa was specified
  end
end
```

BTW, you don't need to specify `return`. Ruby automatically returns the last value calculated.